# Uploading documents via services in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

Does anyone know how to upload documents to a sitefinity site hosted remotely from my desktop machine, via the API or services?

Thanks

Comment: What version? It appears 4 exposes RESTful services through WCF documented here: http://www.sitefinity.com/40/help/developers-guide/deep-dive-client-side-programming-restful-wcf-services-in-sitefinity.html. I would look through that and post more details about what you've tried and what issues you're having.

Answer (score 0):

For any others interested in this, here are some references.

I found some information on a Falafel Software blog post regarding the topic.

http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/basememara/11-11-14/Upload_Documents_Remotely_to_Sitefinity.aspx

...and also on the Sitefinity forums.

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/using-the-web-services-to-upload-documents-to-chosen-libraries.aspx